# How to get timeZoneName as EST instead of EDT and GMT

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have requirement where i want want to show time in EST like 03:32:11 PM EST,

i tried keeping the timeZone as America/New_York but it is returning the time in EDT format

```
 const date = new Date();
      date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
        timeZone: 'America/New_York',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        second: '2-digit',
        timeZoneName: 'short',
      }),

output //10/21/2022, 04:32:19 PM EDT



date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'EST',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    timeZoneName: 'short',
  }),
);
 output : 10/21/2022, 03:32:58 PM GMT-5
```

what should be the timezone to get timeZoneName as EST?

Comment: `America/New_York` is in EDT. EST doesn't start until 6-Nov.

Comment: @esqew So  does it going to change  from EDT to EST automatically after or on 6-Nov?all i wanted here is to display timeZoneName in EST  ,like 03:32:58 EST

Comment: @iamro45 I am stuck with the same issue. Were you able to achieve this by any way ?